# Python Pandas: Changing One column based on another dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following array:

```
Key, Value

Up, a
Up, b
Up, b_regen
Up, c_regen
Down, a
Down, b
Down, b_regen
Down, c
```

Where Value == *_regen change Key to (key)_regen *being wildcard

Output would be:

```
Up, a
Up, b
Up_regen, b_regen
Up_regen, c_regen
Down, a
Down, b
Down, c
Down_regen, b_regen
```

I have gotten this far:

```
x = df['Key'].values[df['Values'].values == 'b_regen'] = 'Up_regen'
```

This works however it's not dynamic. I need the Up/Down _regen part not to be hard coded as above.
Ideally the 'b_regen' value would also not be hard coded and would look for any variable with '_regen' in it. However I think I can get a workaround if I make it into a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `DataFrame` like this:

```
a = pandas.DataFrame([['Up', 'a'], ['Up', 'a_regen'], ['Down', 'b_regen']], columns=['key', 'value'])
>>> a
    key    value
0    Up        a
1    Up  a_regen
2  Down  b_regen
```

You can create a function that determines if the value column ends in `'_regen'` and then apply it your values:

```
def is_regen(s):
    return s[-5:] == '_regen'
```

then just add the string to the end of your keys:

```
a.loc[a['value'].apply(is_regen), 'key'] += '_regen'
>>> a
          key    value
0          Up        a
1    Up_regen  a_regen
2  Down_regen  b_regen
```

Comment: Do you know if possible to set it up so that the '_regen' in the def is_regen function can be passed as a variable versus hardcoded?

Comment: Sure, your function would just take 2 arguments, `def has_substring(s, end): return s[-len(end):] == end`

Comment: Yes but how to you actually pass the arguments within the apply function. You can't simply have a.loc[a['value'].apply(has_substring(s, "regen")), 'key'] += '_regen'. Within the apply function arguments are passed with the "args=" parameter, something like this  a.loc[a['value'].apply(func=has_substring args="regen", 'key'] += '_regen' How ever I can't get this to work.

Comment: What you have will work, args just needs to be an array within the apply function: `a.loc[a['value'].apply(has_substring, args=['regen']), 'key'] += '_regen'`